# Passing argument by value to onClick function

Tags: javascript, for-loop, onclick, pass-by-value

I can't figure out how to pass an argument by value in JavaScript to onClick-function. I have been trying with closure functions but it doesn't seem to work!! aah

```
...

for(var i=0; i<=15; i++){
    blockNr++;
    meal = getMealByCategory(category, i);
    place.innerHTML += "<div class='container-fluid' name='blockName' id='blockName" +
    blockNr + "' onClick='addPrice(meal, 20)'></div>"; //here, always the last meal is sent

    var itemPlace = document.getElementById("blockName"+blockNr);
    itemPlace.innerHTML = meal; //this works fine for all meals
}
```

Comment: So how do you call `onclick` function?

Comment: Use dom manipulation instead of html injection. `document.createElement("div")`...

Comment: Your onclick is binding to the meal variable at the end of the loop, not the value of meal for each iteration, which is why the last meal is always shown. There are plenty of examples of how to assign event handlers in loops to handle this.

Comment: Have you considered using jQuery? You could neaten this up quite a bit, and add a click event: $("#blockName").on("click", addPrice(meal, 20));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is creating a global variable and overwriting it every time you add to the `.innerHTML`. Code in a string can't reference local variables, so what you want isn't possible.

One option would be to concatenate the value into the string.

```
place.innerHTML += "<div class='container-fluid' name='blockName' id='blockName" +
blockNr + "' onClick='addPrice(\"" + meal + "\", 20)'></div>";
```

---

This should work, but is pretty unpleasant. Instead, create your elements with DOM creation methods, and assign a function to the `onclick` property. That function will be able to reference the local `meal`.

And be sure to create a local scope, and declare `meal` with `var`.

```
var meal; 

for(var i=0; i<=15; i++) {
    meal = getMealByCategory(category, i);
    createDiv(meal);
}

function createDiv(meal) {
    blockNr++;
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = "container-fluid"
    div.name = "blockName"
    div.id = "blockName" + blockNr;
    div.onclick = function() {
        addPrice(meal, 20);
    }
    place.appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: Not sure what `meal` is, but this will likely lead to XSS problems

Comment: @Bergi: Likely? That's overstating it. But either way, I indicated that DOM creation would be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

That is because by the time you run the on-click event the loop has fully executed and the value for `meal` is static as the last calculated value.  If this needs to change for each element, you should pass the parameter value to the function, not pass the variable name.  So something like:

```
"' onClick='addPrice('" + meal + "', 20)'></div>";
```

Comment: Not sure what `meal` is, but this will likely lead to XSS problems

Comment: @Bergi `meal` was the variable that is declared a couple of lines before this.

Comment: Yes, but what is its value? Seems to be some HTML.

Comment: @Bergi Who knows.  Whatever `getMealByCategory()` returns.  I don't know how you would think this is HTML, as there is no evidence of that.

Comment: I thought `itemPlace.innerHTML = meal; //this works fine for all meals` would be evidence enough :-) But yes, whenever we don't know what it is we need to escape it properly.

Comment: @Bergi: ..what kind of xss problems? 

function getMealByCategory(category, mealNr){
        var meals = getMealsByCategory(category); /* another js function, calls to php function with jquery ajax, works fine */
        var meal = meals[mealNr];
        return meal;
    }

Comment: @user3857472: If the `meal` contains an `'` (which ends the string literal) or an `"` (which ends the html attribute), you'll get invalid markup. And depending on who creates the meals, that will be a security hole.